# Observable Collection C# unable to access

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, winforms, oop

Two silly doubts:

1. I am unable to access the property `Students` in another class where I reference. Please let me know why am I not able to reference or call it?
2. Can't I declare a variable at class level and access it inside a method inside that class except using `ref` keyword? Say I have a method called Display whose return type is `IEnumerable<Student>` and inside that, I want to call and return `StudentsListDetails`

My class looks like this:

```
public class Service
{
    private ObservableCollection<Student> studentsList;

    public ObservableCollection<Student> StudentsListDetails;

    public StudentEntities StudentEntities { get; set; }

    public ObservableCollection<Student> Students
    {
        get
        {
            if (studentsList == null && StudentEntities != null)
            {
                StudentEntities.Set<Student>().Load();
                studentsList = StudentEntities.Set<Student>().Local;
                StudentsListDetails = studentsList;
            }

            return studentsList;
        }
    } 
}
```

Comment: It's hard to figure out what you're actually asking here. Can you make your question more understable?

Comment: plz Update your question for clarity about the problem.

Comment: @awexfwex: Ok, I want to access StudentsListDetails inside a method that returns IEnumerable<Studen>. Second - I should be able to access "Students" property from other class.

Comment: @loop: I update comment above, please help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure about your problem but i think for first point it will help you:-

1-> You have to access the Students property by using the object of the service class in other class. Like this

```
    Service objService = new Service();
    var lst = objService.Students;
```

2-> Can you put your method in which you want use "StudentsListDetails" and class in which you are writing this method.

You Update about it and i will try to help you if i can.

Comment: Thank you very much, that helps me a lot. I seem to have forgetton many things since didn't code for sometime now.

Answer (score 1):

Ad. 1 since Students is not static in above code, you first have to create an instance of Service class, then you can access Students property

```
Service serv = new Service();
ObservableCollection<Student> students = serv.Students;
```

If having an instance of Service isn't desirable, you want to make Students property (and all fields/methods/properties used inside the code for it) static. Then you access it like:

```
ObservableCollection<Student> students = Service.Students;
```

Ad. 2. If both method and variable are in the same class, you don't need ref/out keywords. You can access and modify it directly (unless modifying has been explicitly disallowed by keywords like const or readonly).

Comment: thank you, I am afraid I am not getting intellisense of variable outside the function although same class. Geez, really pesky